# Is the function a linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is the function a linear operator?
>   $$
> L
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x \\
> y
> \end{pmatrix}
> = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x + y \\
> y + 2
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

**My try:**

I think I have to test additivity and multiplicativity:
$$
\begin{align}
L(u+v) &= L(u) + L(v) \\
L(c \cdot u) &= c \cdot L(u)
\end{align}
$$
Would additivity go something like this?
$$
L(u + v) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
(u+v) + y \\
(u+v) + 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming my guess of your definition, it is not linear, as it does not map the 0 vector to the 0 vector.

Comment: Could I check its linearity with additivity and multiplicity?

Comment: $L(0) = L(2 \cdot 0) = 2 L(0) \iff  L(0) - L(0) = 2 L(0) - L(0) \iff 0 = L(0)$ where the multiplicity is used. (I assumed the scalars are from a field which contains a $2$).

Comment: $L(0) = L(0 + 0) = L(0) + L(0) \iff L(0) = 0$ where additivity has been used.

Comment: Im confused dont both your examples equal to zero so wouldn't the zero vector be there?

Comment: Both examples give that a linear $L$ must map the $0$ vector to the $0$ vector. As your example has $L(0) = (0,2)^\top \ne (0,0)^\top = 0$, it can not be linear.

Comment: I should have said that those $L$ were linear $L$.

Comment: For your $L$, we have $L(0) = (0,2)$. If $L$ was linear, you would have $L(0) + L(0) = L(0 + 0)$, but here $(0,2) + (0,2) = (0,4) \ne (0,2) = L(0+0)$.